# How do I stop my keyboard layout reverting to English USA from English on reboot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Removed English USA from Keyboard settings. English is the only thing in there. Can revert to English after reboot by clicking on EN icon but having to do this every time I reboot is annoyying

Comment: In Language Support / Settings, have you set it as the System-wide default?

Comment: occasionally have this issue under Unity, VERY annoying...